# How to Using a different manifestPlaceholder for each Build Variant in Gradle 6.7.1 +?

Tags: android, gradle

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def mergedFlavor = variant.getMergedFlavor()
    mergedFlavor.manifestPlaceholders = [appPackageId: "myPackageExample"]
}
```

why it doesn't work for me on gradle plugin 4+,but it works on gradle plugin 3+ ??? Help !!!

Comment: What the error messages you got, please can you add any error messages or Logcat

Comment: I want to set ‘applicationId’ into manifestPlaceholders , but it didn't work